On the Abstract Structure Behind Oracle Problems
Here is what I mean by an 'Oracle Problem'.

An universe set or class $U$, a family of queries $\mathcal Q$ of partitions of $U$ and a target element $t\in U$ are fixed. You're not aware of the target element, only the universe and query family, but you are allowed to make a certain amount of questions. In a question, you select a query $P\in\mathcal Q$ and ask an omniscient oracle what set $T\in P$ contains $t$. Your task is to minimize a certain measure of the set $\displaystyle\bigcap T$ in a worst-case scenario.

Many famous problems and games can be modeled as Oracle Problems, such as

The Weighting Coins Puzzle
Some versions of the Knights and Knaves problem
The Poison Wine Problem
The Monty Hall Problem
Mastermind, Wordle and Hangman

Oracle Problems are often the subject of study of Information Theory. A great example of this is in this video, where the YouTube channel 3Blue1Brown talks about how to mathematically approach the Wordle game. However, my (superficial) research on Information Theory could not satisfy a curiosity o'mine: is there an mathematical abstract structure to sets of good queries?
Let's naively define a good set of queries as a subset $\mathcal S\subset\mathcal Q$ with no redundant information, i.e., such that the removal of any query $Q\in\mathcal S$ would increase the measure of the set of possible values of the target $t$. This notion generalizes, for example, the concept of finite linear independence. In fact, consider a Vector Space $U = \mathbb R^n$ and a target element $t\in U$ and suppose a query consists in taking an element $u\in U$ and asking the value of $u\cdot t$ and also the measure we are concerned with is dimension. Then, a set is good if, and only if, it is linearly independent.
This problem as stated is not an Oracle Problem by the definition above, but it is immediate to model it into one by taking the queries as the preimages of the function $f(x)\equiv x\cdot t$.
One well established way to generalize the concept of linear independence is with matroids, so it is natural to ask if this is the structure underlying good sets. This is not the case. For proving this, all we need to know is every maximal independent set in a matroid have the same size. However, if we consider the Oracle Problem where the target is some element of an arbitrary set and the queries are all of its partitions, with the counting measure, then there is one maximal singleton good set, namely the discrete partition, but there are also many greater maximal good sets.
In fact, this is the reason I called this definition naive before: the absence of redundant information is not enough to grantee optimality. Here is a new attempt at a proper definition. Say a set of queries is great if it can be extended to an optimal set, that is, a set of queries with minimum measure. It is no longer obvious such a family of sets do not form a matroid.
This is my question: What is the abstract structure of sets of great questions? Is it matroids or something else? Have this already been proposed and studied before?
